# Python Selenium - Select after clicking dropdown

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to select an option that displays only after you've clicked on the dropdown (see attached image). I have been able to click on the dropdown to get the list, but have not been able to figure out how to click on an option, say option 1, 'Last Day' after the list comes into picture.

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe')
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True

url='https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=0&suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword=data+sc&sc.keyword=data+scientist&locT=C&locId=1154532&jobType='    
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=cap, executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url=url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()

# clicking on dropdown
d = driver.find_element_by_id('filter_fromAge')
d.click()
```

I also tried using the following code (found on another SO answer) but it did not work either:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"ul#css-1dv4b0s ew8xong0")))
```

I'm new to web scraping and not really familiar with XPATHs and how to deal with actions. Help appreciated!

Comment: See solution for your question in Answer section and For your xpath below could be good starting pint https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-for-using-xpath-in-selenium-with-examples/

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: Try using <span class="labelArrow small"></span> to click.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To select the option with text as *Last Day* that displays only after clicking on the dropdown you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=0&suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword=data+sc&sc.keyword=data+scientist&locT=C&locId=1154532&jobType=')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#filter_fromAge>span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='PrimaryDropdown']/ul//li//span[@class='label' and contains(., 'Last Day')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: LastDay]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java script to click on your element. As element is present in DOM but its only appears when click on drop down, so normal click method mau work or may not. But with JS it will always click. Can use below code:

```
day = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Last Day')]") #Identify your element
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", day) # CLick it with help of JS
```

**out Put:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following approach:

```
driver.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/boston-data-scientist-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IC1154532_KO7,21.htm')
driver.maximize_window()

expand_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'filter_fromAge')))
expand_element.click()

target_text = 'Last 3 Days'
target_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="css-1dv4b0s ew8xong0"]/li/span[text()="{}"]'.format(target_text))))
target_element.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="filter_fromAge"]/span[text()="{}"]'.format(target_text))))
```